# Use any method to determine if the series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10}{[6n+11]^{\frac{4}{3}}}$

So I think it converges but I'm not sure

Comment: do you know about LCT and p-test?

Comment: I've heard about the comparison test, but I'm not sure what the p-test is?

Comment: Note that this is bounded by $2/n^{4/3}$. Then use the integral test to conclude convergence.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{10}{(6n+11)^{4/3}}\approx \frac{10}{(6n)^{4/3}}$$ when n is large enough
since$$\sum \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}>\sum \frac{10}{(6n)^{4/3}}$$ and since $\sum \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$ converges by p test so,
$$\sum \frac{10}{(6n)^{4/3}}$$  converges  too

Comment: Just as written by ketan,$\sum \frac{10}{(6n)^{4/3}}$ converges to $3.30279$ while $\sum \frac{10}{(6n+11)^{4/3}}$ converges to $2.06778$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral comparison test
shows that
$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac1{n^p}$
converges for $p > 1$.

Your series has $p = \frac{4}{3}$,
so it converges.